# Store small information

Tags: php

Looking for an idea for a solution to my problem.
I update the page every 24 hours, so I need to check when it was last updated.

My problem is that I do not know where I have to save the date of the last update.
I do not use the DB and do not want to use the files.
I use the API for the data on the website, but I can only get the data.

Is there any option to solve my problem?

Comment: You can't save the date in a dedicated file ?

Comment: You can't store the information in a database, and you can't store it in a file - perhaps start with the list of possibilities that do exist. If the list is "none" then you can't do what you're asking. If the api response includes a last-modified header you can perhaps use that.

Comment: How are you storing the data now as you ase you say your are _update the page every 24 hours_?